# Relatiosn with Matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

For every integer $n>2$ and $A,B,C,D \in M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ we have :

$1) AC-BD=I_{n}$

$2) AD+BC=O_{n}$

Prove that  $CA-DB=I_{n}$ and $DA+CB=O_{n}$.

I tried to prove that $AC=CA$ like the proof of theorem " $AB=I$ , then $BA=I$ " , after that  I tried with multiply and add the relations  but I didn't manage to prove that.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the block multiplication
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A & -B \\ B & A
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
C & - D \\ D & C
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
AC-BD & -(AD+BC) \\ BC+AD & -BD+AC
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix} I_n & O_n \\ O_n & I_n \end{bmatrix}=I_{2n}
$$
Then also
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
C & - D \\ D & C
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
A & -B \\ B & A
\end{bmatrix}
=I_{2n}
$$

Comment: Thanks!!!! Would you like to reccomend a book about it?

Answer (score 0):

To prove that determinant of AC is positive, we solve like that or we use the relations.
I try like that:

$\det(AC)=\det(BD+I_{n})=?$

I thought that $\det(BD+I_{n})=1+\mathrm{Tr}(BD)+\det(BD)$.